# How to stream write a large list of objects in chunks to JSON format in Python?

Tags: python

I want to know how to stream a large list of objects into JSON format in chunks. I have something like this:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class MyObj(BaseModel):
   ....

data = []
with open('file_to_process', 'rt') as fin:
  for x in fin:
     ...
     data.append(MyObj(....))

with open('foo.json') as fout:
  json.dump([x.model_dump() for x in data], fout)
```

This works OK, but when data gets very  big, memory consumption gets very high. I tried using the [json-stream](https://github.com/daggaz/json-stream) library to perform the write. It works OK and reduced the memory consumption, but it seems to iterate and write out one object a time.

```
from json_stream import streamable_list

@streamable_list
def process(f):
  with open(f) as fin:
    for x in fin:
      ...
      y = MyObj()
      yield y.model_dump()

data = process('file_to_process')

with open('foo.json') as fout:
  json.dump(data, fout, indent=2)
```

Is there a way to do the JSON stream write in chunks? Say if there are 1000 objects generated, write it out, then proceed again to the next 1000, etc.

Comment: Well, you can certainly DO that, as long as you postprocess the file to eliminate the border between the lists (that is `\r\n]\r\n[`.

Comment: have you considered an alternative serialization format, like JSON-lines (newline-delimited JSON)?

Comment: It's a bit problematic, because you need to know when to close an object and when to leave it open for more to come, so you have to be flexible with your chunk sizes. Now, that's for *general purpose* packages. If you have knowledge of the structure of your data, you could write a mix of json-stream (say you "open" several nested levels of data), with regular json when you get to levels where serializing all the nodes from there down in one go benefit you a lot without sacrificing too much memory. With knowledge of the data domain it could be feasible.

Comment: " but it iterates one object as a time so runtime is much longer now. " what does this mean exactly? What exactly are you doing?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga "json-stream allows you iteratively generate your data one item at a time, and thus consumes only the memory required to generate that one item... The iterative generation of JSON items provided by json-stream allows the data to be written as it is produced." Thanks.